# JNDI datasource lookup failing using embedded Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using embedded Jetty 9.2 and am trying to setup an Oracle datasource that needs to be accessed via JNDI. I believe I have set this up correctly but it is not working despite spending the best part of a day searching the web. Can anyone help?

Here is my startup code:

```
    final String webdocs = "../abtc_core_war/src/main/webapp";
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext(webdocs, "/");
    webapp.setBaseResource(new ResourceCollection(Resource.newResource(webdocs)));

    final HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    handlers.addHandler(webapp);

    Server server = new Server();
    ServerConnector connector=new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(8080);
    server.addConnector(connector);
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    //Enable parsing of jndi-related parts of web.xml and jetty-env.xml
    org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
    classlist.addAfter(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration", 
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", 
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");

    try
    {
        server.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        server = null;
        throw e;
    }

    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/abtcDS");

    String url = "http://localhost:" + connector.getLocalPort() + "/app";
    System.out.println("URL  ==>  " + url);
```

And here is my jetty-env.xml (which is in the WEB-INF directory of my war):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"   "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="ResourceRef_abtcCoreDatasource" class="hello.org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg></Arg>
        <Arg>abtcDS</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver">
                <Set name="DriverType">thin</Set>
                <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@nonprodcluster:1521/e1abtc_app</Set>
                <Set name="User">user</Set>
                <Set name="Password">pass</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>

    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry">
        <Arg><Ref refid="wac"/></Arg>
        <Arg>Test</Arg>
        <Arg type="java.lang.String">Value</Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

And here is my web.xml resource ref:

```
<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_abtcCoreDatasource">
    <res-ref-name>abtcDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

I am getting two errors. When I start the server I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name javax.sql.DataSource/default

And the lookup of the abtcDS at java:comp/env/abtcDS returns

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'comp/env/abtcDS'

If I try to lookup java:comp/env I get

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env'

So it looks like the whole JNDI system is not initialising.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

verfiy the class entry against **ResourceRef_abtcCoreDatasource** id .it seems it is

hello.org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource ->org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource